# How to remove a given String or char from a String in Java?

Tags: java, string

I'm supplied with a code for a homework problem and I'm trying to analyze what each step does. This program is supposed to remove supplied characters from a String ex: `withoutString("Hello there", "llo")` returns `"He there"`

I'm confused on what `pos` and `remove.length()` and `remove.toLowerCase()` does in this code. Can someone help explain to me? I'm a beginner in Java and I want to understand things instead of simply being given the answer. Thank you.

```
public class WithoutString {

    public String withoutString(String base, String remove) {
        String copy = base.toLowerCase(); 
        int pos = copy.indexOf(remove.toLowerCase());
        while ( pos >= 0) {
            base = base.substring(0, pos) + base.substring(pos + remove.length());
            copy = base.toLowerCase();
            pos = copy.indexOf(remove.toLowerCase());
        }
        return base;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.toLowerCase() means return current string in all lower case. [See #toLowerCase](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase())

```
String test = "Hello World";
String testLoweredCase = test.toLowerCase(); // "hello world"
```

In this code,

```
int pos = copy.indexOf(remove.toLowerCase());
```

It means in the 'copy' string, return the first index that contains the string in 'remove'. [See #indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))

Answer (score 0):

```
int pos = copy.indexOf(remove.toLowerCase());
```

Here `pos` gives the first index of the removable string in the base string.

**For example:**

Your given String: Hello World

Remove String: llo

So, the pos will be: 2

`remove.toLowerCase()` makes your to removable String to lower case.

```
base.substring(pos + remove.length())
```

Here, base is the main string. If String's substring method takes single parameter then it will create a substring from that position to end.
Here, you are taking the pos which are the first index of removable string and adding the length of the removable string. So, you are getting the position after the removable string.

Answer (score 0):

### `remove.toLowerCase()`

This is a trick used to do case-sensitive String comparison - while some String methods do have case-insensitive variants (like `equals` and `equalsIgnoreCase`), for the cases where there is no such method the often used trick is to convert both compared Strings to lowercase (or uppercase). This can be also useful if you're working with some external system (e.g. database) that lacks the case-sensitive comparison where you need it.

Because you don't want to change the case in the resulting String though, you're keeping track of two strings - `base`, which always has the correct case, and `copy` which is its lower-cased variant.

So this method will work just as well for inputs `"Hello there"`, `"LLo"`.

### `pos` and `remove.length()`

In Java, strings are immutable (cannot be changed), so you'll have to create a new String with the result.

How do you find the result of `"Hello there"` minus `"llo"`? You find `"llo"` and use everything that's before this string, and everything that's after it. `pos` is where the `"llo"` substring starts within the whole string, `pos + remove.length()` is where it ends.

### A side note

While you didn't ask about it, there's one more thing that's worth keeping in mind when implementing a string-manipulation method - if it will perform multiple manipulations (like "replace / remove all occurrences"), how will former manipulations affect the later ones?

Example: input `"balloon"`, remove `"lo"`.

Will the implementation return `"balon"` or `"ban"`? That is, after removing `"lo"` once, will it start over from beginning of string looking for matches, or will it continue from the position *after* the replacement / removal it just performed?

The usual approach tends to be the latter, because it only operates on the original input, not on a result of partially modified one. This seems top be more in line with users' expectations. Your method on the other hand uses the former approach. It's not *wrong* per se, but you should be aware of it (and in production code also document it either way). Your code can be modified to use the latter approach by giving appropriate start position as a second parameter to `copy.indexOf()`.

Comment: @RishabhMaurya The posted code attempts to remove every occurrence of the needle, and does so in case-insensitive manner. Your (now deleted) answer only removed a single case-sensitive occurrence.